# find area of interests around 5 square miles

Tags: gis

In web `gis` class using `Postgis`, I want to find area of interests around 5 square miles of a selected point.I have to use `ST_within`.

This is the query I written:

```
select hw1.route,count(*) from hw as hw1, hw as hw2,aoi where 
st_within(hw1.the_geom,aoi.the_geom) group by hw1.route;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ST_Buffer](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) to build a sourronding polygon of radius 5 miles around the point of interest. And then check if your geometry is within or intersects (it depends on your needs) the buffer.

Comment: Thanks. I did exactly same